# How to run MongoDB as a non root user in Linux?

Tags: mongodb, linux, amazon-ec2

I can start MongoDB as `$sudo service mongod start`. When I start without `sudo` it gives me this error:

```
/etc/init.d/mongod: line 58: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/etc/init.d/mongod: line 60: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
Starting mongod: runuser: may not be used by non-root users
```

1) Now, I've changed ownership to the non root user on all mongo directores I could find i.e. `/var/lib/mongo`, `var/log/mongodb`, `data/db`, `var/run/mongodb`

```
$sudo chown -R nonRootUser:nonRootUser [directory]
```

2) I've deleted `mongod.lock` files

3) I've run `--repair` too

It still gives me the same error.

I also tried

```
$mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log

about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 18566
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

mongod.log file says this:

```
2016-03-17T15:03:49.053+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-03-17T15:03:54.144+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
```

It's Amazon Linux. I am able to start it like this $mongod, but I want to run it as daemon so it runs continuously.

The nonRootUser is a new user I created in addition to ec2-user. Maybe there are some config issues relating to running daemon processes if you're not ec2-user?

UPDATE: Changed ownership on everything to ec2-user, still getting exactly the same errors as before.

Comment: Did you use the RPM package or the tar.gz installer?

Comment: I guess rpm https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

This answer is extremely old and covers old versions of MongoDB which using `init` scripts. For `systemd` systems, see the [answer below](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/321156/34077) by [Wernfried Domscheit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32815/wernfried-domscheit).

**OLD ANSWER**

You mention that you used the `rpm` installer for installing MongoDB on the Amazon Linux AMI. When you do this, the `mongod` user is created on the system and all of the appropriate files are created and owned by the `mongod` user. When starting MongoDB installed by the `rpm`, the command must either be run by `root` or run using `sudo`. This is because the init script must execute a change user command so the `mongod` process can be forked as a child of the `mongod` user.

Failure to use `root` or `sudo` to start the service results in the errors you quoted above.

```
/etc/init.d/mongod: line 58: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
/etc/init.d/mongod: line 60: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
Starting mongod: runuser: may not be used by non-root users
```

So, in order to run as a service, you must use `sudo` or `root`. There is no simple way around this except granting the `mongod` user a shell, assigning it a password, logging in as that user, then running the service. This will still result in errors attempting to modify the `ulimits` and is generally not recommended.

To start MongoDB without running it as a service, since you used the `rpm`, the `mongod` binary should be in your path, so the following should work

```
mongod --dbpath /path/to/data --logpath /path/to/mongod.log --fork
```

Note that doing this will run it as the currently logged in user, that means all of the data files as well as `mongod.log` must be writable by that user. Ideally, these files should be owned by that user.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to [use the tarball instead of an installer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/):

1. download from https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.6.3.tgz (use `wget`)
2. extract (`tar xaf mongodb-linux...tgz`) and move to other directory optionally
3. create data dir (`mkdir ~/data`)
4. start as `mongod --dbpath ~/data --fork`

Answer (score 2):

After changing permissions on directories and files don't forget to *log out* and log back in.

I can't still run it as

```
$ service mongod start
```

it can only be run as root.

But alternatively you can run it as daemon like this:

```
 $ mongod --fork --logpath to/logpath
```

Just to be on the safe side I created data/log directory for logpath. And yes you can create other users in addition to ec2-user on Amazon Linux and they can also run mongodb

Comment: These two commands fundamentally different. For the most important difference see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb/67043090#67043090.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `systemctl` then user/group can be defined in service file, e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service`

Can look like this one:

```
[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb /var/lib/mongo
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb /var/lib/mongo
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0700 /var/lib/mongo
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```